# Aligning two range inputs side by side to create an interval picker

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

I came up with an idea of building a range slider by using two different HTML range inputs placed next to each other.

Since there can only be one focused element at a time I came up with a solution of modifying the minimum, maximum and width of the inputs when focus changes between them.

[See my solution](https://jsfiddle.net/sL3jkxcg/) - Using custom styling for webkit range input track and thumb.

#### Example

Range spans between 1 to 100. If first input is on 20 and the second input gets focus I will modify the first inputs maximum value to 20 and set the minimum value of the second input to 21. I will then set the width of the inputs to a percentage value dependent on the current value. So the first input described above will get the width of 20% and the second 80% to match values selected.

#### The issue

Since the thumb of the input will align left when set to its minimum value and to the right when set to the maximum value there is a small "jump" when focus changes and I modify the min and max values of the range inputs. The width of the thumb is set to `1rem` and that value must be taken into account somehow together with the current value of the input itself (i think..). I just can't get that last part right.

Comment: You have a built-in slider input type. Why would you need to build your own?

Comment: As far as I know there is no native dual range-input @FDavidov

Comment: Check this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_range.asp

Comment: If you take a look at my example (https://jsfiddle.net/74mmjL15/) you can see that I'm trying to build a interval picker using two range inputs. The native one only support one value picker and I want to have two different to select an interval @FDavidov

Comment: I see. Well, there are other options I would check (like having two, one next to the other), but I guess this is not what you are looking for,

Comment: Well that is exactly what I've been developing, using two range inputs next to each other. I am now looking for a solution to the alignment issue. Everything described above in my initial question @FDavidov